# Using an array of iterators for reading sparse information

Tags: c++, iterator, sparse-matrix

I have a long timeframe where I want to store every time a neuron "fires" during this time. Since "firing" is a discrete event, this can be done by simply recording the time of each event into a C++ vector, thereby creating a much sparser representation then storing information about every point in time.

What makes this difficult is that I want to deal with several neurons at once. My solution to this problem has been to create a class includes a map from each neuron's identifier (an integer) to that neuron's vector:

```
using namespace std;
typedef pair<int,vector<int> > Pair;
typedef map<int,vector<int> > Map; 

class SpikeTrain{
public:
    Map * train;//Spike train
    double * dt;//timestep
    int * t_now;//curent timestep (index)
    vector<int>::iterator * spikeIt;//Array of iterators for traversal.

//Methods, etc;

};
```

The map part of this works fine. The problem comes when I try to  ask: how many events occur at any given time step. This is an easier question to ask then to answer, because, if you remember, only the times at which events occur on each neuron are stored. I therefore turn to the strategy of using iterators initializing an array of iterators:

```
void SpikeTrain::beginIterator(){
     spikeIt= new vector<int>::iterator[N()];
     t_now = new int(0);
     int n=N();
     for(int i  = 0;i<n;i++){
        if((*train)[i].size()>0){
            spikeIt[i] = (*train)[i].begin();
         }
     }
}
```

Where the first time of each event is pointed to by the iterator corresponding to the individual neuron [N() is simply the number of neurons, i.e. vectors, that I am counting over], that is, the first entry in its vector of spikes. I then attempt to traverse my sparse sudo-matrix by looking at each time, counting over the number of neurons that spike at that time and, if a neuron does spike, moving the corresponding iterator in my array to the next entry in its vector:

```
bool* SpikeTrain::spikingNow(){
    bool * spikingNeurons = new bool[N()];
    int n = N();
    for (int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        if(*(spikeIt[i]) ==(*t_now)){
            spikingNeurons[i] =true;
            spikeIt[i]++;
        }
    }
    (*t_now)++;
    return spikingNeurons;
}
```

My problem, then, comes in attempting to access each iterator in the array to compare to the current time. I get a

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code = 1,address = 0x0)

at:

```
if(*(spikeIt[i]) ==(*t_now))
```

Comment: There is *way* too much `new` going on in this code.

Answer (score 0):

If any vector in `*train` is empty, the corresponding iterator in `spikeIt` is never initialized - but you are dereferencing and incrementing it anyhow. This exhibits undefined behavior.

Further, there is no attempt to prevent iterators from incrementing past the end of their vectors.